# In a MySQL select statement, can I split a text column and then sum the parts as floats?

Tags: mysql, select, casting, split

I have a MySQL column that is defined as text. The column, if not null, always contains a list floats separated by a newline character.

I have been tasked with making the total amount of those floats searchable with min and max constraints.

In the where clause, I would like to be able split the column by a newline character and sum all of the resulting strings as floats.

Is this possible?

Comment: Fix your data structure so you store the numbers as *numbers*, not strings.  This will require another table with one row per value and row in the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to define your own function.Here is an example I just tested, hope it is helpful to you(BTW: It is not advisable to implement such kind of functions in mysql. Maybe it is better to let the application servers to compute it instead of mysql :)).

```
DELIMITER $$    

CREATE function split_n_sum(str text) returns DECIMAL(36,4) 
begin
declare location int;
declare result decimal(36,4);
declare tmp_str varchar(1024);
declare _delimiter varchar(128);

set _delimiter='\r\n';
set result=0;

set tmp_str=ltrim(rtrim(str)); 

set location=INSTR(tmp_str,_delimiter);
if location=0 and length(tmp_str)>0 then
    set result=cast(tmp_str as decimal(36,4));
    set tmp_str='';
end if;    

while location<>0 do
    set result = result+cast(substring(tmp_str,1,location-length(_delimiter)) as decimal(36,4));
    set tmp_str=substring(tmp_str,location+length(_delimiter), length(tmp_str));
    set location=INSTR(tmp_str,_delimiter); 
end while;

if length(tmp_str)>0 then
    set result=result+cast(tmp_str as decimal(36,4));
end if; 

return result;
end$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can: Use a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION splitAndSum(inputStr VARCHAR) 
RETURNS FLOAT;
BEGIN
DECLARE summedValues FLOAT;
DECLARE tempVal FLOAT;
DECLARE subString VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE tempLength INT;

SET subString=inputStr;
SET tempLength=0;
WHILE(TRUE) DO;
SET splitStr=MID(0,instr(subString," "));
SET tempLength=length(subString);
SET subString=MID(instr(subString," "));
SET tempVal=CAST(splitStr AS FLOAT);
SET tempVal=CAST(splitStr AS FLOAT);
SET summedValues=summedValues+tempVal;
IF(length(subString)==tempLength) break;
DONE;
RETURN summedValues;
END;
```

Call the function:

```
SELECT splitAndSum("1 2 3");
```

Should return: 6
Function needs to be tested...